# When are components defined in functions evaluated? (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

Suppose I have a component that renders a list item:

```
const ListItem = ({ itemName }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {itemName}
    </div>
  )
}
```

And because this list item is used in many places in my app, I define a custom hook to render the list and control the behavior of each list instance:

```
const useListItems = () => {
  const [ showList, setShowList ] = useState(true)
  const { listItemArray, isLoaded } = useListContext() // Context makes api call
  
  const toggleShowList = setShowList(!showList)
  
  function renderListItems() {
    return isLoaded && !!listItemArray ? listItemArray.map((itemName, index) => (
      <ListItem key={index} isVisible={showList} itemName={itemName}/>
      )) 
      : 
      null
  }
  // Some other components and logic...
  
  return {
    // ...Other components and logic,
    renderListItems,
    toggleShowList,
  }
}
```

My first question is, **when will the array of ListItems actually be evaluated** ? Will the jsx resulting from renderListItems() be calculated every time renderListItems() is called? Or would it happen every time useListItems() is called?

Second question: if I call useListItems() in another component but **don't** call renderListItems(), does that impact whether the components are evaluated?

I have been struggling to find an answer to this, so thanks in advance.

Comment: > when will the array of ListItems actually be evaluated -- when you call `useListItems()`, so every render.  

`renderListItems()` is a consumer, so if it's not called, it's not using the array, but array is referenced befor it, so it's in the above scope, so it will be used no matter if you use `renderListItems()` or not.

Comment: Thanks, so I figured. I guess what I wonder then is...is that something to be concerned about if I don't actually call renderListItems() in a particular component? Obviously it won't actually render to the page, but does running the function here impact performance a lot or is it pretty minimal compared to the rendering itself?

Comment: it depends on how you implemented `useListContext` if the reference to that array is not changing for no reason,then it wouldn't cause a re-render upon call to `useListItems`